# W/AudioFlinger( 57): write blocked for 1068 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0x40d98ec0

Tags: java, android, c++, media-player, android-mediaplayer

i try to call the API of mediaplayer.cpp for play a mp4 file .
But there is no picture, sound off and on sometime.

```
 #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include "PlayerListener.h"
    #include <binder/IPCThreadState.h>
    #include <binder/ProcessState.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace android;

    char flag = 0;
    CedarMediaPlayer mp;
    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {


        String8 filepath(argv[1]);

        sp<ProcessState> proc(ProcessState::self());
        ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
        printf("demo start\n");


        PlayerListener mPlayerListener;
        printf("new a MediaPlayer done\n");


        mp.setOnPreparedListener(&mPlayerListener);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(&mPlayerListener);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(&mPlayerListener);
        mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(&mPlayerListener);
        mp.setOnInfoListener(&mPlayerListener);
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(&mPlayerListener); 

        mp.setDataSource(filepath);
        mp.setLooping(0);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AUDIO_STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDisplay(0);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.9f);
        printf("set source mp4 done \n");
        mp.prepareAsync();

        printf("wait huanchong\n\n");

        if(flag == 1)
        {
                printf("i get 1 start \n");
                mp.start();
        }
    //  mp.release();
        printf("play start\n");
        while(1);
        return 0;
}
```

logcat output:

```
D/mydemo  (106)(f:PlayerListener,l:33)PlayerListener::PlayerListener!

D/mydemo  (  106): 

D/        (   57): has_audio:1 has_video:1

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): =============================================

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_PLATFORM: A23-JB42

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_SVN_REPOSITORY: xxxx

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_SVN_VERSION: xxxx

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_SVN_COMMITTER: 93eddbd6e60f302b9fcf428e2cdee0eb2dd5925c

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_SVN_DATE:   Mon Aug 24 17:29:52 2015 +0800

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): CDX_RELEASE_AUTHOR: gushiming

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): =============================================

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x0], ret[0x0]

V/aw_demux(   57): DemuxSetDataSource

D/cedarx_demux(   57): cedarx_demux_create: 0x0

D/aw_demux(   57): (f:aw_demux_open, l:848) ==== aw_demux_open url:fd://20?offset=0&length=48098544====

D/awplayer(   57): <CdxParserPrepare:575>: source uri 'fd://20?offset=0&length=48098544'

D/awplayer(   57): <__FileStreamCreate:500>: local file 'fd://20?offset=0&length=48098544'

D/awplayer(   57): <__FileStreamConnect:427>: (21/0/48098544) path:'file:///mnt/extsd/beyond1~1.mp4'

D/awplayer(   57): <__FileStreamConnect:453>: :16:[00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70 69 73 6f 6d 00 00 02 00]

D/awplayer(   57): <__FileStreamGetMetaData:344>: redriect url 'file:///mnt/extsd/beyond1~1.mp4'

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserProbe:902>:  --- probe: it is mov parser

D/awplayer(   57): <CdxParserCreate:534>: Good, it's 'mov'

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserOpen:844>: --- c->bSeekAble = 1

D/awplayer(   57): <CdxParserCreate:537>: parser type(0)

D/awplayer(   57): <MovTop:4988>: ---- compatible = isomiso2avc1mp41

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseTkhd:2731>: tkhd width = 1024, height = 768

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseMdhd:2882>: -- language = und

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseStsd:3670>: stsd width = 1024, height = 768

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseCtts:4116>: track[0].ctts.entries = 3348

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseStsz:4048>: -- sample_size = 0

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseTkhd:2731>: tkhd width = 0, height = 0

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseMdhd:2882>: -- language = und

D/awplayer(   57): <MovParseStsz:4048>: -- sample_size = 0

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserInit:787>: ***** mov open success!!

D/aw_demux(   57): aw_demux_open: aw_dmx->pParser(0x40c58c70), parserType[0], is it forbiden:)?

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:469>: --- codecformat = 115

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:475>: ---- frame rate = 15

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:483>: width = 1024, height = 768

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:486>: extradataSize = 42

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:514>: ********* audio 0************

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:515>: ****eCodecFormat:    4

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:516>: ****eSubCodecFormat: 0

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:517>: ****nChannelNum:     2

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:518>: ****nBitsPerSample:  16

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:519>: ****nSampleRate:     22050

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:520>: ****nAvgBitrate:     0

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:521>: ****nMaxBitRate:     0

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:522>: ****extradataSize    5

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:523>: ***************************

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:563>: streamNum = 2, videoNum = 1, audioNum = 1, subtitleNum = 0

D/awplayer(   57): <CdxMovSetStream:5752>: mvhd = 273200, 

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:576>: -- mov duration = 273200

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:592>: --i = 0, stsd_type = 1, stream_index = 0, nb_streams = 2

D/CdxMovParser(   57): <__CdxMovParserGetMediaInfo:592>: --i = 1, stsd_type = 2, stream_index = 0, nb_streams = 2

D/aw_demux(   57): <PrintMediaInfo:363>: *********PrintMediaInfo begin*********

D/aw_demux(   57): <PrintMediaInfo:377>: fileSize = 0, bSeekable = 1, duration = 273200, audioNum = 1, videoNum = 1, subtitleNum = 0 

D/aw_demux(   57): <PrintMediaInfo:395>: ***Video[0]*** eCodecFormat = 0x115, nWidth = 1024, nHeight = 768, nFrameRate = 15, nFrameDuration = 0, bIs3DStream = 0 

D/aw_demux(   57): <PrintMediaInfo:413>: ***Audio[0]*** eCodecFormat = 0x4, eSubCodecFormat = 0x0, nChannelNum = 2, nBitsPerSample = 16, nSampleRate = 22050 

D/aw_demux(   57): <PrintMediaInfo:429>: *********PrintMediaInfo end*********

D/aw_demux(   57): <aw_demux_open:948>: aw_demux_open success.

W/Demux_Component(   57): (f:CreateDemuxPorts, l:906) no subtitle?[0][0]

D/Demux_Component(   57): (f:DemuxGetParameter, l:365) OMX_IndexVendor GetMediaType, default normal tmp

D/CDX_Player(   57): (f:CDXPlayer_GenerateCedarXMediaInformations, l:2075) parser don't care outer rotate, but will process picture self-rotation[0] 

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:setNativeWindow_l, l:1013), set layerId[0]

W/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:prepareAsync, l:1457) property key[media.cedarx.chipver] get value[3], len[1] 

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): play vps[0] before CDX CMD_PREPARE_ASYNC!

D/CDX_Player(   57): same vpsspeed[0]

D/CDX_Player(   57): hnd_demuxer 0x40c58980

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x1], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x2], ret[0x0]

D/VideoDec_Component(   57): (f:CedarvCodecInit, l:417) vdec output format default to PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12

D/VideoDec_Component(   57): (f:CedarvCodecInit, l:437) config vbvBufferSize[0]KB

E/awplayer(   57): <VeChipId:122>: [40;31mcannot open /dev/sunxi_soc_info

E/awplayer(   57): [0m

D/awplayer(   57): <InitializeVideoDecoder:263>: chipId=0

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x3], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x5], ret[0x0]

D/VideoRender_Component(   57): CDX use VideoRenderMode = 0

D/CDX_Component_Common(   57): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x4], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Player(   57): components info:[url ], [demux 0x40c58980], [vd 0x41a2a038], [vr 0x40ccc118], [ad 0x40c58f20], [ar 0x40ccc570], [sd 0x0], [sr 0x0]

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:finishAsyncPrepare_l, l:1403) mVideoWidth[1024], mVideoHeight[768], notifyListener_l(MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE_)

D/mydemo  (  106): (f:onVideoSizeChanged, l:58) receive onVideoSizeChanged message!size[1024x768]

D/mydemo  (  106): (f:onPrepared, l:38) receive onPrepared message!  flag = 1

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:play_l, l:860) cdx_state=0x2, sleep 10ms to wait cdx to play, wait_time=0!

D/awplayer(   57): <DecodeAudioStream:909>: ==============================pAudioDecoder->pBsInFor->bitrate:5167

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:play_l, l:855) cdx play alread!

W/CDX_Player(   57): only one audio track!

D/AudioRender_Component(   57): >>>>>audio render init sample_rate:22050 channels:2

D/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1199) audio set config start time to [0]us

V/codec_audio_plan_v3(   57): in normal mode, speaker on,****LINE:64,FUNC:set_normal_path, speaker_on=2

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): video render display_size:1024x768, format:0x4

D/CedarXPlayer(   57): (f:StagefrightVideoRenderInit, l:2847) mDisplayFormat[0x32315659], new CedarXDirectHwRenderer

D/HwDisplay(   57): (getInstance 1138)

D/HwDisplay(   57): (hwd_layer_set_src 180)

D/HwDisplay(   57): width: 0x400, height: 0x300

D/HwDisplay(   57): width: 0x40000000000, height: 0x30000000000

D/HwDisplay(   57): set fb.format 88 72 end

W/MediaPlayer(  106): info/warning (3, 0)

I/CedarMediaPlayer(  106): Info (3,0)

D/mydemo  (  106): (f:onInfo, l:64) receive onInfo message! media_info_type[3] extra[0]

D/VideoRender_Component(   57): (f:VideoRender_ComponentThread, l:1291) video set config start time to [133333]us

D/Clock_Component(   57): (f:ClockSetConfig, l:549) notifyStartToRun, Mediatimebase=[0]ms walltimebase=[2171]ms

W/AudioFlinger(   57): write blocked for 1063 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0x40c4dec0

D/audio_hw_primary(   57): out_standby

W/AudioTrack(   57): releaseBuffer() track 0x423ad830 name=0 disabled, restarting

W/AudioFlinger(   57): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service

V/codec_audio_plan_v3(   57): in normal mode, speaker on,****LINE:64,FUNC:set_normal_path, speaker_on=2

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[7745]us, because diff[-4195721]us, latency[85034]us, mediaClock[4203566]us

W/VideoRender_Component(   57): (f:VideoRender_ComponentThread, l:1175) videorender sleep too long[220894]us, media_video_time:333333 system_time:112439

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[425705]us, because diff[-955065]us, latency[85034]us, mediaClock[1380870]us

W/AudioTrack(   57): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x423ad830 name=0user=000030cc, server=00002709

W/AudioFlinger(   57): write blocked for 1081 msecs, 3 delayed writes, thread 0x40c4dec0

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[528879]us, because diff[-974776]us, latency[28299]us, mediaClock[1503755]us

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[565024]us, because diff[-1032425]us, latency[85034]us, mediaClock[1597549]us

W/AudioTrack(   57): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x423ad830 name=0user=00003a8f, server=000030cc

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[621759]us, because diff[-1098353]us, latency[28299]us, mediaClock[1720212]us

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[657904]us, because diff[-1018148]us, latency[85034]us, mediaClock[1676152]us

W/AudioTrack(   57): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x423ad830 name=0user=00004452, server=00003a8f

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[676181]us, because diff[-1106519]us, latency[113197]us, mediaClock[1782800]us

W/AudioFlinger(   57): write blocked for 1071 msecs, 6 delayed writes, thread 0x40c4dec0

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[843664]us, because diff[-965500]us, latency[85034]us, mediaClock[1809264]us

W/AudioTrack(   57): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x423ad830 name=0user=00005568, server=00004ba5

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[946839]us, because diff[-1043967]us, latency[28299]us, mediaClock[1990906]us

W/AudioRender_Component(   57): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1361) fatal error! config wall time base again by newTime[1354640]us, because diff[-1034389]us, latency[84897]us, mediaClock[2389129]us

W/AudioFlinger(   57): write blocked for 1058 msecs, 9 delayed writes, thread 0x40c4dec0
```

Look like memory access is crossing the line But I don't know how to solve

---

2017-2-8 up

But I use this code can successfully play a aac files

```
./3mydemo1 /mnt/extsd/a.aac
```

and the logcat :

```
W/AudioFlinger(   58): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service

D/mydemo  (  117): (f:PlayerListener, l:33) PlayerListener::PlayerListener!

D/mydemo  (  117): 

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): =============================================

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_PLATFORM: A23-JB42

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_SVN_REPOSITORY: xxxx

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_SVN_VERSION: xxxx

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_SVN_COMMITTER: 93eddbd6e60f302b9fcf428e2cdee0eb2dd5925c

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_SVN_DATE:   Mon Aug 24 17:29:52 2015 +0800

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): CDX_RELEASE_AUTHOR: gushiming

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): =============================================

D/CDX_Component_Common(   58): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x0], ret[0x0]

V/aw_demux(   58): DemuxSetDataSource

D/cedarx_demux(   58): cedarx_demux_create: 0x0

D/aw_demux(   58): (f:aw_demux_open, l:848) ==== aw_demux_open url:fd://22?offset=0&length=7182674====

D/awplayer(   58): <CdxParserPrepare:575>: source uri 'fd://22?offset=0&length=7182674'

D/awplayer(   58): <__FileStreamCreate:500>: local file 'fd://22?offset=0&length=7182674'

D/awplayer(   58): <__FileStreamConnect:427>: (23/0/7182674) path:'file:///mnt/extsd/a.aac'

D/awplayer(   58): <__FileStreamConnect:453>: :16:[ff f1 50 80 3e 7f fc de 02 00 4c 61 76 63 35 37]

D/awplayer(   58): <__FileStreamGetMetaData:344>: redriect url 'file:///mnt/extsd/a.aac'

W/awplayer(   58): <__AacParserProbe:1615>: aac probe ok.

D/awplayer(   58): <CdxParserCreate:534>: Good, it's 'aac'

D/awplayer(   58): <CdxParserCreate:537>: parser type(22)

W/awplayer(   58): <__AacParserControl:1297>: not implement...(265)

W/awplayer(   58): <AacInit:1227>: AAC ulDuration:289386

D/aw_demux(   58): aw_demux_open: aw_dmx->pParser(0x411f17a0), parserType[22], is it forbiden:)?

D/aw_demux(   58): <PrintMediaInfo:363>: *********PrintMediaInfo begin*********

D/aw_demux(   58): <PrintMediaInfo:377>: fileSize = 7182674, bSeekable = 1, duration = 289386, audioNum = 1, videoNum = 0, subtitleNum = 0 

D/aw_demux(   58): <PrintMediaInfo:413>: ***Audio[0]*** eCodecFormat = 0xf, eSubCodecFormat = 0x0, nChannelNum = 2, nBitsPerSample = 16, nSampleRate = 44100 

D/aw_demux(   58): <PrintMediaInfo:429>: *********PrintMediaInfo end*********

D/aw_demux(   58): <aw_demux_open:948>: aw_demux_open success.

W/Demux_Component(   58): (f:CreateDemuxPorts, l:870) no video?[0][0]

W/Demux_Component(   58): (f:CreateDemuxPorts, l:906) no subtitle?[0][0]

D/Demux_Component(   58): (f:DemuxGetParameter, l:365) OMX_IndexVendor GetMediaType, default normal tmp

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): (f:setNativeWindow_l, l:1013), set layerId[0]

W/CedarXPlayer(   58): (f:prepareAsync, l:1457) property key[media.cedarx.chipver] get value[3], len[1] 

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): play vps[0] before CDX CMD_PREPARE_ASYNC!

D/CDX_Player(   58): same vpsspeed[0]

D/CDX_Player(   58): hnd_demuxer 0x4119ec68

D/CDX_Component_Common(   58): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x1], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Component_Common(   58): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x3], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Component_Common(   58): (f:CDX_CreateComponent, l:57) create component type[0x4], ret[0x0]

D/CDX_Player(   58): components info:[url ], [demux 0x4119ec68], [vd 0x0], [vr 0x0], [ad 0x4119e758], [ar 0x41207d70], [sd 0x0], [sr 0x0]

W/CedarXPlayer(   58): unkown video size after prepared

D/mydemo  (  117): (f:onPrepared, l:38) receive onPrepared message!  flag = 1

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): (f:play_l, l:860) cdx_state=0x2, sleep 10ms to wait cdx to play, wait_time=0!

D/awplayer(   58): <DecodeAudioStream:909>: ==============================pAudioDecoder->pBsInFor->bitrate:171921

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): (f:play_l, l:860) cdx_state=0x2, sleep 10ms to wait cdx to play, wait_time=1!

D/AudioRender_Component(   58): >>>>>audio render init sample_rate:44100 channels:2

D/AudioRender_Component(   58): (f:AudioRender_ComponentThread, l:1199) audio set config start time to [0]us

D/Clock_Component(   58): (f:ClockSetConfig, l:549) notifyStartToRun, Mediatimebase=[0]ms walltimebase=[20]ms

V/codec_audio_plan_v3(   58): in normal mode, speaker on,****LINE:64,FUNC:set_normal_path, speaker_on=2

D/CedarXPlayer(   58): (f:play_l, l:855) cdx play alread!

W/CDX_Player(   58): only one audio track!
```

So I guess is MP4 video output memory cross-border happened